# Does AWS Elasticsearch Service with Kibana allow Logstash X Pack Management/Monitoring?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash

I am using AWS Elasticsearch Service, with a cluster version 7.4. I realized that Kibana  on AWS Elasticsearch Service have a few features missing compared to the ELK stack and wanted to check if the AWS Elasticsearch Service variant supports Logstash X-Pack Monitoring and Management. The logstash version I am using is 6.8.

My main goal is to be able to monitor all my logstash pipelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not.

The AWS Elasticsearch version is based on the open source distribution of Elasticsearch that were released by Elastic until version 7.10.

The management and monitoring features are part of the Elastic license, those features are not available in the open source distribution.

Just keep in mind that Elastic changed its [license](https://www.elastic.co/pricing/faq/licensing) and there are no more open source distributions of the stack, so Amazon and a few others created a fork of the last open source version, 7.10, called [Opensearch](https://opensearch.org).

In the future the AWS Elasticsearch service will probably be renamed.

Comment: Until version 7.10.2 to be exact ;-)

Comment: In that case, is there any other way to monitor pipeline status from Logstash to AWS Elasticsearch service?